# Silverlight Binding in Pivot Control

Tags: silverlight, binding, windows-phone-7

I have a design question : In a pivot view (three "pages"), I have a lot of bindings. Well, about 12 items in each pivot view (TextBox, Map...).

I realized that these binding were slowing a lot the load of my view. But the binding on the first "page" of my pivot is the only one that needs to be loaded. I can put a progress indicator and load in a thread or something my other data (in fact, the binded data will be set only after an HTTPWebRequest).

How can I tell that to my application ? Like "onLoadPageX: bind items"

Thanks a lot, I don't know if i'm clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite vague but there are lots of options around showing a loading state, defering binding and having lots of controls in a pivot:

If you need to do anything that may take time then do it off the UI thread.

If you're doing something which takes time then you should show an indication to the user that something is happening. This could be a message or animation, depending on the likley time period and the rest of the application.

If your content is highly dependent upon data loaded from the web, be sure to have appropriate timeouts on failing to load the data. Also have useful messages if there is no data connection available.

If your UI is highly dependent on details loaded externally you could look at adding the controls to the UI once you know what you need to display.

If the UI will always have the same controls but different content in them, you could consider data-binding to objects which have placeholder content which is updated when the relevant information is downloaded from the web service.

If you have lots of items in your pivot you should consider defereing the loading of individual items so that you don't load them before they are needed. Only load the data on the items next to the one displayed. This way they appear preloaded to the user but ease the impact on the system.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a [RoutedEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventhandler%28VS.95%29.aspx) for the [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28VS.95%29.aspx) event of each [PivotItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.pivotitem_members%28VS.92%29.aspx). This event is fired when a particular `PivotItem` page is loaded; there is also a corresponding `Unloaded` event for when the page unloads, in case you need to free any resources.

Comment: ok, so I should programmatically add the UI elements in my Loaded callback ?

Comment: You could add them programmatically; it really depends on the UI elements you have on that page. For instance, if you just have a ListBox you can have it declared in XAML, but have visibility turned off, load the bound resource item with the data and then make the item visibile.